# postsharp logging is not triggering

Tags: c#, postsharp

this is the very first time I am trying to use **postsharp**.

I have added new **class library** to my solution and add postsharp using **nuget manager**.
my concern is to refer this class library in my other projects in the solution.

in my class library I hav e added new class

```
[Serializable]
    public class MethodLogAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
    {
        public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnEntry" + args.Method.Name);          
        }

        public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("OnExit" + args.Method.Name);   
        }

        public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("OnException" + args.Method.Name);   
        }
    }
```

Now I have reffer this in my another class library project in same solution.

```
[MethodLogAspect]
        public DataLayer()
        {
        .......
        }
```

but logins are not happening. no error can found also. please help me with a solution

Comment: Did you install PostSharp NuGet package in another class library (the one where DataLayer is located)?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your class name like this :

```
[Serializable]
public class MethodLogAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    // Your logging methods
}
```

And then in your other class methods use it like this :

```
[MethodLog]
Public void GetData()
{
   // Your code
}
```

Comment: you are not getting any error, and with this little code it is difficult to understand what could be the issue